# Плавная смена прозрачности кнопки в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация, button, color

Пишу класс анимаций. Начал писать код на смену прозрачности у кнопки, но столкнулся с проблемой. Хотел сделать плавность у прозрачности и поплыл в потоках. Фактический всё работает, но если я сначала наведу, потом уберу курсор, а потом снова наведу начинаются подёргивания прозрачности. Подскажите как это правильно сделать. Вот пример кода кнопки и класса:

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{

    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    eventAnimation.ChangeTransparancy(this, 150);
    MouseEntered = false;
    Invalidate(); 
}
protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    eventAnimation.ChangeTransparancy(this, 255);
    MouseEntered = false;
    Invalidate();
}
```

Класс анимаций:

```
public class Animation
{

    public void ChangeTransparancy(Button button, int transparancyCount)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => ThreadTransparancyAction(button, transparancyCount));
        thread.Start();            
    }
    
    public void ThreadTransparancyAction(Button button, int transparancyCount)
    {
        while (button.BackColor.A != transparancyCount)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            LerpTransparancy(button, transparancyCount);
        }
    }

    private void LerpTransparancy(Button button, int transparancy)
    {

        Color buttonColor = button.BackColor;

        int NewTransparancyValue = (button.BackColor.A + transparancy) / 2;

        if(NewTransparancyValue == transparancy - 1 && transparancy == 255)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, buttonColor.R, buttonColor.G, buttonColor.B);
        }
        else
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(NewTransparancyValue, buttonColor.R, buttonColor.G, buttonColor.B);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните пож в тегах к вопросу, это что WPF или WinForms ? Если это WinForms то я признаться не понимаю зачем такие извращения, берите WPF и делайте там любую анимацию без костылей. WinForms совсем не заточен под это, не занимайтесь садомазохизмом)

Comment: Согласен с Павлом. На винформсах это делается сложно и это по-факту бессмысленная задача.

Comment: @PavelPopov  спасибо за ответ. Прямо в название указано, что я использую форму. Но я не могу перейти, так как у меня уже проект, который использует 3 dll, 3 шрифта, 600+ строк кода, а до этого я с WPF не работал, но возьму на заметку. Жду пока дальше ответа, если кто-то подскажет.

Comment: все что ты назвал это мелочь. Да и 600 строк это мало, особенно учитывая что тебе не нужно переходить на другой язык - только на другой юай. А если ты код написал правильно - то это вообще безболезненно проходит... Ну а если неправильно...то сам виноват). Лучше совета чем этот уже не будет - это я тебе гарантирую) Любой другой совет - это костыли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что позволяется одновременная работа скольких угодно потоков анимации, которые, конфликтуя друг с другом, беспорядочно меняют значения прозрачности. Нужно, чтобы позволялась одновременная работа только одного потока. Строго говоря, тут вообще не нужны потоки, периодический запуск метода в WinForms уже реализован в виде стандартного класса Timer.

Например, создадим такой класс для анимации прозрачности таймером:

```
public sealed class ButtonAnimation:IDisposable
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _t;
    Button _button;
    int _transparancyCount;

    public ButtonAnimation(Button b, int transparancyCount)
    {
        _button = b;
        _transparancyCount = transparancyCount;
        _t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _t.Interval = 100;
        _t.Tick += T_Tick;
        _t.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_button.BackColor.A == _transparancyCount)
        {
            ((System.Windows.Forms.Timer)sender).Enabled = false;
            return;
        }

        LerpTransparancy(_button, _transparancyCount);
    }

    private void LerpTransparancy(Button button, int transparancy)
    {
        Color buttonColor = button.BackColor;

        int NewTransparancyValue = (button.BackColor.A + transparancy) / 2;

        if (NewTransparancyValue == transparancy - 1 && transparancy == 255)
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, buttonColor.R, buttonColor.G, buttonColor.B);
        }
        else
        {
            button.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(NewTransparancyValue, buttonColor.R, buttonColor.G, buttonColor.B);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_t != null)
        {
            _t.Enabled = false;
            _t.Dispose();
            _t = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда использование будет выглядеть так:

```
ButtonAnimation anim;

public void ChangeTransparancy(Button button, int transparancyCount)
{
    if (anim != null)
    {
         //если анимация уже идет, прекратим её
         anim.Dispose();
         anim = null;
    }

    anim = new ButtonAnimation(button, transparancyCount);
}
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Проверю. Если ещё будут у меня вопросы можно вам сюда или ещё куда-нибудь написать?

Comment: @Сергей если по этому коду - можно здесь, в комментариях. Если по чему-то другому, лучше отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Нет, код прекрасно работает, буду разбирать, как это точно работает. Спасибо!

Comment: можете потом посмотреть новый вопрос, там тоже же про кнопки.